# what is the difference between these two pointer declaration

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here I have a 2D array. I want to declare a pointer to point to the first row of the array. First I did something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   int arr[2][2]={{6,2},{3,4}};
   int *ptr=arr;

   printf("%d",*(ptr+0));
}
```

First row of the 2D array is also a array. Similar type of pointer declaration for a 1D array don't give any warning. Why am I getting warning during compilation.

> [Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
>   default]

The following didn't give any warning

```
int main ()
{
   int arr[2][2]={{6,2},{3,4}};
   int (*ptr)[2]=arr;

   printf("%d",*(ptr+0));
}
```

Comment: It's the same as the difference between a house and a kitchen, or between a human and a toe.

Comment: Here's the warning for the `printf` line in the second snippet, in case you missed it: **"check.c:8:17: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]"**

Answer (score 2):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the line

```
int *ptr=arr;
```

the *expression* `arr` has type "2-element array of 2-element array of `int`" (IOW, `T` is "2-element array of `int`").  Since the expression `arr` is not the operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to 2-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[2]`, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

This is why you got the warning for the line above, but not for

```
int (*ptr)[2]=arr;
```

since in that case the types match correctly.

Given the declaration

```
int arr[2][2]={{6,2},{3,4}};
```

the following are all true:

```
Expression         Type            Decays To            Equivalent Value
----------         ----            ---------            ----------------
       arr         int [2][2]      int (*)[2]           &arr[0][0]
      &arr         int (*)[2][2]                        &arr[0][0]
      *arr         int [2]         int *                &arr[0][0]
    arr[i]         int [2]         int *                &arr[i][0]
   &arr[i]         int (*)[2]                           &arr[i][0]
   *arr[i]         int                                  arr[i][0]
 arr[i][j]         int                                  
&arr[i][j]         int *
```

So `arr`, `&arr`, `arr[0]`, `&arr[0]`, and `&arr[0][0]` all evaluate to the same *value* (the address of the first element of an array is the same as the address of the array itself), but the *types* are all different.

A very important point I want to get across (especially because it's shown up in a couple of other answers) is that array objects *do not* store any pointer values.  If you looked at the contents of `arr` in memory, you'd see something like the following:

```
     +---+
arr: | 6 | arr[0][0]
     +---+ 
     | 2 | arr[0][1]
     +---+
     | 3 | arr[1][0]
     +---+
     | 4 | arr[1][1]
     +---+
```

No storage is set aside anywhere for any pointers.  When your code is compiled, any expressions that refer to arrays are *replaced* with pointers to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is an array of arrays of integers while `ptr` is a pointer to an integer. In an array of arrays you need two levels of indirection to reach an integer (`arr[0][0]`) while in a pointer you need just one (`ptr[0]`). You can assign an array of elements of a certain type to a pointer to an element of the same type, but not if the types are different which is the case here.

As you can see, they are two different things so the compiler does a good job on whining on your assignation.

Answer (score -2):

2D arrays contain (as arrurri mentioned) a pointer which points to an array of pointers and each of those point to the actual elements. So, arr is a pointer to pointers and each indexed value of it (arr[i]) is a pointer to a row.

So, what you need to do is ptr=arr[0]; instead.

Comment: Arrays *do not* contain any pointers to any elements; array expressions are *converted* to pointer expressions as necessary.  If you examine a 2D array byte by byte, you will not find any pointer values within it; you will only find the array elements themselves.

Comment: My bad phrasing that one. I meant that each element of the 1st dimension in the array (each arr[i]) is a pointer (pointing to an array of size j), while each arr[i][j] is a value and arr itself is a pointer to an array of size i (which, as mentioned, has pointers as elements). Isn't that correct?

Comment: No, it is not.  Neither `arr` nor any `arr[i]` store a pointer value.  During translation, the *expressions* `arr` and `arr[i]` are replaced with pointer values as necessary, but no storage is set aside for any pointers within the array object.  See the example layout at the end of my answer.